# Django Inline form validation ignored partly filled form

Tags: python, django

I have got the code from https://github.com/adandan01/mybook, the code is working fine, even when I have updated it to Django 2. It's very simple project for adding a person in a form, and his/her relatives in the inline form. Everything works but when I add a relative name and forget to add his relationship, and submitted the form, unfortunately, that record will not pass the validation but will give no error messages as well. Django will ignore the entire record. For example, the record for Hawra in the image, will not be saved and Django will remove it. For this simple App there are only two fields to be filled (name and relationship), but I'm working on app with 8 fields, and it will be difficult to lose the data. is there any way to make django do the validation in the formset/subform as long as any fields have data and will ask the user to fill all required fields?

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('profile-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

form.py

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Profile
    exclude = ()


class FamilyMemberForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = FamilyMember
    exclude = ()


FamilyMemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Profile, FamilyMember,
                                        form=FamilyMemberForm, extra=1)
```

views.py

```
class ProfileCreate(CreateView):
   model = Profile
   fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

class ProfileFamilyMemberCreate(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile-list')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super(ProfileFamilyMemberCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet(self.request.POST)
    else:
        data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet()
    return data

def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    familymembers = context['familymembers']
    with transaction.atomic():
        self.object = form.save()

        if familymembers.is_valid():
            familymembers.instance = self.object
            familymembers.save()
    return super(ProfileFamilyMemberCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

[image: image1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here [django inline_formset - form.empty_permitted = False doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778252/django-inline-formset-form-empty-permitted-false-doesnt-work)

I had to add the following code before if (familymembers.is_valid():...) in the create and update class, so, now Django will show the error if I entered data in the Name field only and will tell me the Relationship field is required.

```
if familymembers.is_valid() == False:
   return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form,familymembers=familymembers ))
```

[image]